# Error being thrown while number is greater than 999 using decimalformat() (calculator app)

Tags: java, android

I'm making calculator app on android.
It always makes an error when I want to calculate number that is over 999.
For example :
I type 3 + 6 than = and it's calculating and print out the result it's 9, than I want to add another number, for example 1, than after the result (9) has printed out, I press + so it would add another number, and I put 1 there, and the program works, it printed out the result 10.
But then I type 1000 than I type + and 1 than = and I get the result 1001, than I want to add another number to it, so I click +, than the program stop.

This is my design code

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="mathapp.esolindo.com.mathapp.CalculatorActivity"
android:clickable="false">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text=""
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="12"
    android:id="@+id/etDisplay"
    android:background="#ffededed"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:text=""
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="12"
    android:id="@+id/etResult"
    android:background="#ffededed"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etDisplay"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etDisplay"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etDisplay"/>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etResult"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etResult"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etResult">

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEight"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNine"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDiv"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text=":"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFour"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFive"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSix"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMul"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="x"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThree"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMin"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnZero"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDot"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="."
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEqual"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:text="C"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tableLayout"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code

```
    package mathapp.esolindo.com.mathapp;

    import android.os.Message;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
    import javax.script.ScriptEngine;  

    public class CalculatorActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button
    btnOne,
    btnTwo,
    btnThree,
    btnFour,
    btnFive,
    btnSix,
    btnSeven,
    btnEight,
    btnNine,
    btnZero,
    btnDot,
    btnDiv,
    btnMul,
    btnMin,
    btnPlus,
    btnEqual,
    btnClear;
private EditText
    etDisplay,
    etResult;
boolean clear;
String appendToetDisplay = "";
String appendToetResult = "";
String appendOperator = "";
double result = 0;
char operator = ' ';
String pattern = "#,###,###.########";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

    clear = false;
    if (clear)
    {
        etDisplay.setText("");
        etResult.setText("");
        clear = false;
    }

    btnOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
    btnTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);
    btnThree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnThree);
    btnFour = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFour);
    btnFive = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFive);
    btnSix = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSix);
    btnSeven = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSeven);
    btnEight = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEight);
    btnNine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNine);
    btnZero = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnZero);
    btnDot = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDot);
    btnDiv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
    btnMul = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMul);
    btnMin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMin);
    btnPlus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
    btnEqual = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEqual);
    btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    etDisplay = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDisplay);
    etResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etResult);

    btnOne.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnThree.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnFour.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnFive.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSix.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSeven.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnEight.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnNine.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnZero.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnDiv.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMul.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMin.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnDot.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnEqual.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnClear.setOnClickListener( this);

    etDisplay.setText("");
    etResult.setText("");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_calculator, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (clear)
    {
        etDisplay.setText("");
        etResult.setText("");
        clear = false;
    }

    int id = v.getId();

    switch(id) {
        case R.id.btnClear:
            etDisplay.setText("");
            etResult.setText("");
            appendToetDisplay = "";
            appendToetResult = "";
            appendOperator = "";
            result = 0;
            operator = ' ';
            break;
        case R.id.btnOne:
        case R.id.btnTwo:
        case R.id.btnThree:
        case R.id.btnFour:
        case R.id.btnFive:
        case R.id.btnSix:
        case R.id.btnSeven:
        case R.id.btnEight:
        case R.id.btnNine:
        case R.id.btnZero:
            appendToetDisplay = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
            appendToetResult = ((Button) v).getText().toString();

            if(operator == '=')
            {
                result = 0;
                operator = ' ';
                appendOperator = " ";
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnDot:
            //Do something
            break;
        case R.id.btnDiv:
            if (appendToetDisplay.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please input a number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(operator == '=')
            {
                appendToetResult = String.valueOf(result);
                compute();
                operator = '/';
                //appendOperator = " : ";
                appendToetDisplay = " : ";
                etResult.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                compute();
                operator = '/';
                //appendOperator = " : ";
                appendToetDisplay = " : ";
                etResult.setText("");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnMul:
            if (appendToetDisplay.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please input a number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(operator == '=')
            {
                appendToetResult = String.valueOf(result);
                compute();
                operator = '*';
                //appendOperator = " x ";
                appendToetDisplay = " x ";
                etResult.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                compute();
                operator = '*';
                //appendOperator = " x ";
                appendToetDisplay = " x ";
                etResult.setText("");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnMin:
            if (appendToetDisplay.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please input a number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(operator == '=')
            {
                appendToetResult = String.valueOf(result);
                compute();
                operator = '-';
                //appendOperator = " - ";
                appendToetDisplay = " - ";
                etResult.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                compute();
                operator = '-';
                //appendOperator = " - ";
                appendToetDisplay = " - ";
                etResult.setText("");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnPlus:
            if (appendToetDisplay.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please input a number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(operator == '=')
            {
                appendToetDisplay = decimalFormat.format(result);
                etDisplay.setText(etDisplay.getText().toString() + appendToetDisplay);
                compute();
                operator = '+';
                //appendOperator = " + ";
                appendToetDisplay = " + ";
                etResult.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                compute();
                operator = '+';
                //appendOperator = " + ";
                appendToetDisplay = " + ";
                etResult.setText("");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnEqual:
            if (appendToetDisplay.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please input a number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                compute();
                operator = '=';
                //appendOperator = " = ";
                appendToetDisplay = " = ";
            }
    }

    etDisplay.setText(etDisplay.getText().toString() + appendToetDisplay);
    etResult.setText(etResult.getText().toString() + appendToetResult);

    //etDisplay.setText(decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(etDisplay.getText().toString())));
    //etResult.setText(decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(etResult.getText().toString())));

}

private void compute() {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(etResult.getText().toString());
    appendToetResult = "";
    if (operator == ' ')
    {
        result = num;
    }
    else if (operator == '+')
    {
        result += num;
    }
    else if (operator == '-')
    {
        result -= num;
    }
    else if (operator == '*')
    {
        result *= num;
    }
    else if (operator == '/')
    {
        result /= num;
    }
    else if (operator == '=')
    {
        // Keep the result for the next operation
    }

    etResult.setText(decimalFormat.format(result));
}

    }
```

Thankyou.

Comment: If it's crashing, that suggests there's going to be an exception in the log. Look at that, and try to work out what's going on. If that doesn't help, try to cut this down to a *short* example (not the 325 lines you've currently posted) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: try debugging your app. hope you will find solution why and where is error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your compute method it looks like you're trying to put a decimal number into an Integer, try this:

```
Double num = Double.parseDouble(etResult.getText().toString().replace(",","."));
```

There is also something wrong with your decimalformat pattern. Using "0.00" instead won't crash your app.